# Magento change the top menu from header to sidebar

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I recently started to develop on magento and it is really confusing. I decided to change the position of top-menu from the header.phtml to the main layout life.

SO I moved `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>` from header.phtml to `2Columns-right.phtml` and now the menu is not showing up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have local.xml file in your theme, can you use this in your default handler:

```
<reference name="header">
    <action method="unsetChild"><name>topMenu</name></action>
</reference>
<reference name="right">
    <action method="insert"><blockName>top.menu</blockName></action>
</reference>
```

If you don't have local.xml file just create one in the layout folder of your theme and populate it with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="header">
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>topMenu</name></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="right">
            <action method="insert"><blockName>top.menu</blockName></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Revert the changes in header.phtml and 2columns-right.phtml
Clear the cache and you are ready to go.

Comment: Why is it this hard to learn these thing? Can you please point me a good resource that takes it from basic.

Comment: Well, Magento is complex. You can find the very basics here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/intro-to-layouts also check this: http://alanstorm.com/layouts_blocks_and_templates